# How to understand the list comprehensions in making list in python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, which will be *converted* to another list which has elements of list type, since each element is a list, we can insert the natural number at the head. Let's put:

```
    l = [('c++', 'compiled'), ('python', 'interpreted')]
    lx = []
    for z in xrange(len(l)):
        y = [x for x in l[z]]
        y.insert(0, z)
        lx.append(y)
    print lx
    [[0, 'c++', 'compiled'], [1, 'python', 'interpreted']]
```

Look, job done, it works in that way. Except any of the followings

Neither:

```
    l = [('c++', 'compiled'), ('python', 'interpreted')]
    lx = []
    for z in xrange(len(l)):
        y = [x for x in l[z]]
        lx.append(y.insert(0, z))
    print lx
    [None, None]
```

Nor:

```
    l = [('c++', 'compiled'), ('python', 'interpreted')]
    lx = []
    for z in xrange(len(l)):
        y = [x for x in l[z]].insert(0, z)
        lx.append(y)
    print lx
    [None, None]
```

Not to mention:

```
    l = [('c++', 'compiled'), ('python', 'interpreted')]
    lx = []
    for z in xrange(len(l)):
        lx.append([x for x in l[z]].insert(0, z))
    print lx
    [None, None]
```

Works, why is that? I noticed such as:

```
y = [x for x in l[z]]
```

is no *one cycle execution* in debug step by step, which is just beyond my impression of expression in other languages.

Comment: `>>> [].insert(0, 1)` `>>>`

Comment: Short version: `lx = [[i, v[0], v[1]] for i, v in enumerate(l)]`

Comment: @Matthias or - if the assumption is that there's always a 2-tuple, then `[[i, a, b] for i, (a, b) in enumerate(l)]` will be more efficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `insert` method does not return anything, which in Python is equivalent of returning the `None` constant. So, for example after this line:

```
y = [x for x in l[z]].insert(0, z)
```

`y` will **always** be `None`. And that is what you append to `lx`, hence the result. Your first snippet is the correct approach. The question has nothing to do with list-comprehensions.

Comment: And were the OP to really want to use a list-comp - they're probably after `lx = [[i] + list(el) for i, el in enumerate(l)]` - and not do insert at all...

Comment: @JonClements: That was the syntax I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @JonClements Excellent